# Getting place name information using GoogleDistance Matrix in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

### I am looking at the [**Google-Distance matrix here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

---

According to Docs if we provide latitude & longitude values we we be replied back with information back from google

---

***I tested with a sample*** :: `Latitude`=12.918494 `Longitude`=77.669387

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.918494,77.669387&destinations=12.961323,77.647415&language=tr-TR&sensor=false&option=driving&units=metric

**I got a JSON response**::

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "28, 4th Cross Road, HAL 3rd Stage, Hal, Puttappa layout, New Thippasandra, Bangalore, Karnataka 560008, Hindistan"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "14, Sarjapur Main Road, Ambalipura, Harlur, Bangalore, Karnataka 560102, Hindistan"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "10,5 km",
                  "value" : 10544
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 dakika",
                  "value" : 1119
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

---

**What i am trying to achieve**::

- I want to get the value `Bangalore(cityname)` from the Json
- I could parse the Json and get it but problem is if say we give some
  other co-ordinates  the address could be longer and seperated by
  coma's so i can't predict where the `cityname` will be

---

**What i am trying to achieve**::

Is there a way like a function using which i can get the `Bangalore` as we do in `Geocoder`

*Note*:: I dont wan't to use `geocode` & i am trying to achieve using this

---

I am new to android, please go easy with answers
Hope i am clear, Thanks

Comment: hi refer my this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129937/update-map-location-dynamically/23130375#23130375](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129937/update-map-location-dynamically/23130375#23130375)

Comment: @Simple Plan..... Can i use that answer when i am using android Emulator ? ..... I don't have a mobile device ..... does Geocoder work with emulator or we have to use that code in android mobile compulsory ?

Comment: yaa off course pass some city name and try.